# regex optional repetitive group

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Suppose the following string:

`some text here [baz|foo] and here [foo|bar|baz] and even here [option].`

I've managed to get matched only by this ugly regex ([Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT7oG5/4)):

```
/(?:
  \[
    (?:
      \|?
      ([^\|\[\]]+)
    )?
    (?:
      \|?
      ([^\|\[\]]+)
    )?
    (?:
      \|?
      ([^\|\[\]]+)
    )?
  \]
)/ugx
```

The point is that I need matches to be grouped by square brackets.
So currently I do have result I need:

```
[
  {
    "match": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 16,
        "end": 19,
        "value": "baz"
      },
      {
        "group": 2,
        "start": 20,
        "end": 23,
        "value": "foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 35,
        "end": 38,
        "value": "foo"
      },
      {
        "group": 2,
        "start": 39,
        "end": 42,
        "value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "group": 3,
        "start": 43,
        "end": 46,
        "value": "baz"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "match": 3,
    "children": [
      {
        "group": 1,
        "start": 63,
        "end": 69,
        "value": "option"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result is correct but that regex is limited to the number of repeating blocks in the pattern.
Is there some workaround to make it match all options inside sqare brackets?

Comment: You could pull all values between `[]` with `preg_replace_callback` then explode on `|`.

Comment: Using PCRE style engines you will only get a fixed match of capture groups. If you quantify capture groups within a larger group, the capture groups get overwritten if they can match again. This is not a problem in Dot-Net. So you can either do it the way chris85 mentions, or you can use the `\G` construct to pick out individual values (1 per match) inside of the brackets.

Comment: @chris85 sure, it can be done that way. But I would like to get all of of the values just from regex output.

Comment: What do you mean by _regex output_? It's all regex output. Remember, you can't get it in one shot..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @sln.!
I mean single regex. Without external routines.
P.S. .Net is not an option here. Project I am working on runs on PHP.

Comment: You know, even with the `\G` anchor, you'd  need a _callback_ to see if it's a new set of brackets (based on which group matched). I'm afraid there is no way around a callback. You could use split instead to just get each `[..]` inside brackets, then split each on `|`. Basically 2 splits. Those are the only options, sorry man.

Comment: Small fyi. The alternation is not a special character inside classes, to minimize toothpick's you could just use `[^|\[\]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to produce capturing groups recursively within a pattern since engine doesn't provide you with such an ability. Saying that, you have two options:

1. Building a Regular Expression based on number of occurrences of pipe
   `|` in your input string.

This way you can build a single regex with most possible repetitive patterns of `([^][|]+)` that will do a group match as you desire:

```
$pattern = (function () use ($string) {
    $array = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= substr_count($string, "|"); $i++) {
        $array[] = $i == 0 ? '([^][|]+)' : '([^][|]+)?';
    }
    return implode("\|?", $array);
})();
```

By giving an input string like:

```
some text here [baz] and here [you|him|her|foo|bar|baz|foo|option|test] and even here [another].
```

Cooked regex would be:

```
~\[([^][|]+)\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?\|?([^][|]+)?]~
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/mP1mH4/1)

And then you can simply use it:

```
preg_match_all("~\[$pattern]~", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/isnnT)

That's a workaround to show that you can save time and avoid headache in building your Regular Expression only and Regular Expressions are not a simple - handy solution always.

2. Benefit from other language functionalities.

Above workaround doesn't bring a solid solution. It is doing much work that is not needed. Below code does fit the job:

```
// Capture strings between brackets
preg_match_all('~\[([^]]+)]~', $string, $matches);

$groups = [];

foreach ($matches[1] as $values) {
    // Explode them on pipe
    $groups[] = explode('|', $values);
}
```

Output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => baz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => you
            [1] => him
            [2] => her
            [3] => foo
            [4] => bar
            [5] => baz
            [6] => foo
            [7] => option
            [8] => test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => another
        )

)
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/LNKNj)